# How do I install an older R package?

Tags: r, package, random-forest

I am trying to install the R package [bigrf](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bigrf/) using the following command:

```
install.packages('bigrf')
```

However, I receive this error:

> Warning in install.packages: package 'bigrf' is not available (for R version 3.0.2).

I understand that the package was not built for R version 3.0.2, but is it not possible for me to install it regardless with the understanding that it might not have complete forward compatibility?

Comment: There isn't a windows binary available for that package at all - you'll need to build it from source.

Comment: Thanks, @Dason! What does it mean to build it from source? Does it entail downloading the package source ('bigrf_0.1-6.tar.gz')?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The safest thing to do would be to download the last version that the package was built for ([link](http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/old/)) and run the code on that version.

The easiest way to rebuild a package from source is using [R-Studio](http://www.rstudio.com).

They have a good [walkthrough](http://www.rstudio.com/ide/docs/packages/building).  You will need to use the **devtools** package as well.

Comment: Thanks, @Christopher Louden! I'll check out the walkthrough to build this package from source.