# bigRF asking for R version 3.1

Tags: r, package, random-forest

There's a similar question out there ([How do I install an older R package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19791405/how-do-i-install-an-older-r-package)), but in my instance, bigRF installs, but then I get an error when I try to load it. What's interesting is that the other SO post indicates that bigRF only works in previous versions of R, while the error is saying that I need a future version of r (3.1) than the current version (3.0.2).

```
library(bigrf)
Loading required package: bigmemory
Loading required package: bigmemory.sri
Loading required package: BH
bigmemory >= 4.0 is a major revision since 3.1.2; please see packages
biganalytics and and bigtabulate and http://www.bigmemory.org for more information.
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.0/Resources/library/bigrf/libs/bigrf.so': dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.0/Resources/library/bigrf/libs/bigrf.so, 6): Library not loaded: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/lib/libR.dylib
Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.0/Resources/library/bigrf/libs/bigrf.so
Reason: Incompatible library version: bigrf.so requires version 3.1.0 or later, but libR.dylib provides version 3.0.0
In addition: Warning message:
package ‘bigrf’ was built under R version 3.1.0 
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘bigrf’
```

Thoughts on how to resolve?

Comment: Have you tried to install from the source code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, looks like `install.packages("bigrf", type="source")` works.